# How to remove duplicates from a string?

Tags: c#, string, duplicates, character

The code is supposed to put all letters into lower case and change j to i, which it does. But I'm trying to take out any duplicate letters.

example inputted string = jjjaaaMMM  expected output string = jam

what actually happens    real output string = m       please help I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
                    string key = Secret.Text;
        var keyLow = key.ToLower();
        var newKey = keyLow.Replace("j", "i");
        var set = new HashSet<char>(newKey);
        foreach (char c in set)
        {
            Secret.Text = Char.ToString(c);
        }
```

Comment: What is your expected behaviour with `jjjaaaMMMjjj`? `jaM` or `jaMj`?

Comment: Would you be ok with “maj” ? Since hash set doesn’t guarantee order to my knowledge...

Comment: If you are more specific with your desired output we can open this question again

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is entirely the `=` in

```
Secret.Text = Char.ToString(c);
```

it needs to be `+=`

```
Secret.Text += Char.ToString(c);
```

You were overwriting each value with the next.

However you could just use *linq*

```
Secret.Text = string.Concat(key.ToLower().Replace("j", "i").Distinct());
```

or probably more efficiently from [@Ben Voigt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt) comments

> Since you have a sequence of `char`, it's probably more efficient to
>   call the `string` *constructor* than `Concat`

```
Secret.Text = new string(set.ToArray());

// or 

Secret.Text = new string(key.ToLower()
                            .Replace("j", "i")
                            .Distinct()
                            .ToArray());
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[String.Concat Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=netframework-4.8)

> Concatenates one or more instances of String, or the String
>   representations of the values of one or more instances of Object.

[Enumerable.Distinct Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.8)

> Returns distinct elements from a sequence.

Comment: Since you have a sequence of `char`, it's probably more efficient to call the string constructor than `Concat`.

Comment: @BenVoigt yeah good point, thanks updated and attributed

Answer (score 0):

Others may answer the question directly. I'll provide an alternative. As always with string manipulation, there's a [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex) for that.

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(.)\1*", "$1");
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use Linq approach:

```
var text = key.ToLower().Distinct().ToArray();
```

Don't forgot add  `using System.Linq`

Comment: With this, `var text` would be a `char[]` rather than a `string`

Comment: Yes it's true. string text = new string(key.ToLower().Distinct().ToArray()); it's more appropiated